# Is there option to change string in second argument of replaceAll, accessed by capture group

Tags: java, regex

I write a program replacing String in which words are delimited by '-' or '_' (`word1-word2-word3`... or `word1_word2_word3`... or any combination of those), to camel case format: `word1Word2Word3`...
I wanted to do it like this:
`str.replaceAll("[-_]([a-zA-Z0-9])", "$1".toUpperCase());` and half of it sorta works: I get resutl of: word1word2word3... - looks like, toUpperCase() didn't have any effect, so my questions are: why is it so and how to make it work - preferably using `replaceAll()`

- Sample input:    `word1_word2_word3`
- Expected output: `word1Word2Word3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`replaceAll(Function<MatchResult, String>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) method of `Matcher`:

```
str = Pattern.compile("[-_]([a-zA-Z0-9])")
    .matcher(str)
    .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1).toUpperCase());
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/Urk6I1) showing that:

```
String str = "word1_word2-word3";
str = Pattern.compile("[-_]([a-zA-Z0-9])")
    .matcher(str)
    .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1).toUpperCase());
System.out.println(str);
```

Outputs:

```
word1Word2Word3
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is working solution for your mentioned problem :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] deliminators = {'-', '_'};
        String input = "word1-word2-word3_word1_word2_word3";
        char[] output = "word1-word2-word3_word1_word2_word3".toCharArray();

        int index = 0;
        for (char element : input.toCharArray()) {

            if (ArrayUtils.contains(deliminators, element)) {
                ArrayUtils.remove(output, index);
                index++;
                output[index] = Character.toUpperCase(output[index]);
                continue;
            }
            index++;
        }
        output[0] = Character.toUpperCase(output[0]);

        String.valueOf(output).replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll("_", "");
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(output).replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll("_", ""));
    }
```

Kindly acknowledge , it should work directly for your use-case.

Comment: While this might "do the task", it does not answer the question as asked, especially as per the title of the question.